# I don't know how to describe it but how do i make a scrollbar with levels points like in internet explorer in the security area?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is a screenshot of what i mean i marked it with a circle.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [TrackBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control!

Answer (score 0):

You want a **Vertical Slider**.

Cf. http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0470__Windows-Presentation-Foundation/VerticalHorizontalSlider.htm